# How to add JS plugin via Yarn to Rails 6 app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, yarnpkg, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a Rails 6 app and added already a few plugins using yarn and webpacker. But always guided by a tutorial.

Now I want to add this one:

```
yarn add @types/waitme
```

The plugin got downloaded to node_modules/@tpyes/waitme

What are now the next steps to make the plugin work? I know that I have to include it in my application.js but i would like to understand how this works.

Right now my application.js looks like this:

```
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import "channels"
import "bootstrap"
import "../stylesheets/application"
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';

Rails.start()
ActiveStorage.start()

$(function() {
})
```

I use `import` but what's next?

Answer (score 0):

That's a type definition, not a library; you'll want to install the library alongside the definition.

```
npm install --save waitme
```

Then use the plugin as you would any jquery plugin.

```
$('#elem').waitMe({})
```